# Magento 2- How to Import cross sell products with CSV?

Tags: magento2, cross-sells, import-products

I have many products in my Magento2 store. I want to assign one product as cross sell product of all products. 
Is there any way to assign cross sell product with CSV product import ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **crosssell_skus** column in your **CSV** file. You need to provide list of SKUs separated by comma for that column.